# Lambda Function - File Structre

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Given the Lambda Function file structure below

[Lambda File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHQDb.png)

If this line is in my .js file: readFile("./html/product.html")

Where in the structure would the "html" folder be placed?
What exactly is the "." in the "." in the path mean?

Currently the function can not find the product.html file and thats because the "html" folder does not exist.  I want to know where to put the "html" folder so I can place the "product.html" file so the function can locate the file correctly

Would the "html" folder be placed at the same level as the "src" folder, or would the "html" folder be placed inside the "src" folder?

Answer (score 0):

"." represents the current directory where the generatePage.js is present. "html" folder must be created inside the "src" folder.